# Open enable location app settings in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, location

In case of Location Permission denied forever, I want to lead user to permission settings for them to enable the location permission for flutter. I used `app_settings` library and also `system_settings` but both of them lead to the enable location screen and not the permission screen itself. I am using `location` package and it is not internally provided in the package. Is there any way to open app specific permission settings in flutter in order to properly lead users to enable location in case of permission denied forever?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this plugin [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

Use below method to open App Settings

```
PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();
```